# How to block a user from my instagram webfeed?

Tags: blocking

I have a joomla website, and use a module to get a feed from Instagram based on a tag (#). But i have a user that keeps taggin with this tag. Is it possible to blog the user so that his images do not show on my web page even if he uses the tag that i use for my feed? I have tryed to block the user in Instagram, but his images still comes up in my feed..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own custom module to get feed and filter manually by blocking the user_id

Comment: Thanks :) - do you have any idea on hov to create a "blocking sentence"?

Comment: if(data.data[i].user.id != "123456"){ // add image }

Answer (score 0):

You might have to delete your comments or remove tags because they will not automatically be removed even after blocking that user.

source: http://viralkick.com/blog/block-someone-instagram/